# What is the localization of Q[x]/(x) at 0

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, localization

Q is a rational field. Q[x] is polynomial ring over Q 。(x) is maximal ideal of Q[x].
Take Q[x]/(x) as a module over Q[x]. Then what is Q[x]-module Q[x]/(x) localize at 0??

I think the result is 
Q[x]/(x) \ otimes_{Q[x]}Q(x) but on the other hand, from another way, I know it should be Q[1/x]/Q.

But how can I prove they are isomorphism?

Comment: This looks like homework and is not appropriate for MO.  Have you read the FAQ?

Comment: Sorry. In fact, I am using very general framework to revise the constructing injectives in Grothendieck category. I want to test this machinary using this example. However, I suddenly found that I could not prove this isomorphism 

Comment: Do you mean localized at the point x=0, or localized at the prime ideal (0)?

Comment: I am sorry. The multiplicative set should be S=Q[x]-(0)

Comment: Connected to Scott's answer, you may also like to note that 
$\mathbb Q[x]/(x) \otimes_{\mathbb Q[x]}\mathbb Q(x)  = 0$
since you can always take any basis element
$r\otimes f$ and rewrite it as $r\otimes fx = rx\otimes f = 0$.

Also, just by the recognition that $\mathbb Q[x]-(0)$ is your multiplicative set, you'll be able to see that the module vanishes; basically by the same argument again: x annihilates all of $\mathbb Q[x]/(x)$, and thus, if $x$ suddenly is invertible, we can take any $r\in\mathbb Q[x]/(x)$ and rewrite its image in the localization to $rx/x = 0/x = 0$.

Comment: Maybe I'm being dumb.  Q[x]/(x) is just the set Q with a Q[x] action in which x acts as 0.  Localizing involves making x act invertibly, so kills everything.

Answer (score 7):

If you localize Q[x] at zero, you get the field of rational functions Q(x), so your module localizes to a vector space over this field (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_module)).  Your module is finitely generated, in fact by a single element, so you get a vector space of dimension zero or one.  To decide which is correct, we can use Proposition 2.1 in Eisenbud's *Commutative algebra (with a view toward algebraic geometry)*: If M is finitely generated, then $M[U^{-1}] = 0$ if and only if M is annihilated by an element of U.  In this case, x is such an annihilating element, and your localized module is zero.  Therefore, your first answer is correct, and your second answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't $Q[x]/(x)$ just $Q$. In general $Q[x]/(x-\alpha)$ is just evaluation of all polynomials at alpha.

Then localization does nothing as we already have a full field of fractions.

Comment: yes it is. Q as a Q[x]-module
